# правильная ли загрузка контента?

Tags: php, ajax

на одной странице есть форма добавление и сразу же отображение результата у виде таблицы, отображение идет с помощью ***ajax***, в консоле в строке ***response*** выводится весь html код таблицы из вводимыми данными из файла get_data.php.

Вопрос:

1)насколько это верно что ответ приходит в HTML?

2)как сделать так, что бы только данные подгружались сразу в готовую HTML

//вывод всех записей

```
   var inProcess = false;
                      function show() {
                        if (inProcess) return;
                        inProcess = true;
                            $.ajax({
                            method:"POST",
                            url: path +"/main/data", 
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html){
                            inProcess = false;
                            $("#content").html(html);
                          }
                        });
                      } 

//добавить запись

        $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
            var fio= $('#form-name').val();
                $.ajax({
                url:path +"/main/add",
                method:"POST",
                data:{'fio':fio},
                success:function(res)
                {   
                    json = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                    alert(json.answer + ' - ' + json.info);
                    if(json.answer == 'добавлено'){
                    document.getElementById("form-name").value = ""; 

                    show(); //вывод записей
                    }

                }
            })
        });
```

//контроллер загрузки самой HTML таблицы из скрипта show()

```
    public function dataAction(){ 
        $data = new Data;
        $list = $data->postsList();
        $get_page = $data->page;
        include PATH_ROOT.'/application/views/main/get_data.php';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Вполне нормально, можно не заморачиваться с формированием структуры на фронте

2) В идеале - php должен отдавать только готовый кусок html, который нужно вставить